# Alternative to Grave character ' ` ' in javascript to render ASP code

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net, .net

I am trying to render asp file using Server.Execute in javascript. What I got is Error of using the backtick character. How could I possibly solve this.

Following is my code snippet.

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    var t = window.innerWidth;
    getScreenResolution(t);
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    var t = window.innerWidth;
    getScreenResolution(t);
});
//............................getScreenResolution method    
var Desktop_status, mobile_status;

function getScreenResolution(t) {
   console.log(t);
    768 < t && 1 != Desktop_status && 
    (mobile_status = !(Desktop_status = !0), $("#responsive-loader").html(`<% Server.Execute("cmd/cmd-assets/includes/home-files/load-desktop.asp") %>`), init()), 
    t <= 768 && 1 != mobile_status && 
    (mobile_status = !(Desktop_status = !1), $("#responsive-loader").html(`<% Server.Execute("cmd/cmd-assets/includes/home-files/load-mobile.asp") %>`), init())
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message

Comment: Also why this? `!(Desktop_status = !0`

Comment: Thanks for instant reply, its giving error of invalid character in IE11

Comment: https://caniuse.com/template-literals